# WordPress Gutenberg core/heading block (wp-block-heading)

Tags: filters, block-editor, sidebar

I am really not sure how to write the code. How do I get all the headings from the page? To be specific, `core/heading`. I wanted to make a sidebar so that the user can just jump from one section to another. Please see the image below.

[image]

Comment: You mean an outliner or table of contents? Such a block already exists in Gutenberg as part of the full site editing initiative, you can see its source code here https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/trunk/packages/block-library/src/table-of-contents

Comment: Hi Tom. Thanks for the response. Yes, like table of contents. How do I find every heading(core/heading), add ID, and add heading link to sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

Update on this. I got the answer! I followed this simple code from
https://goran-s.in.rs/table-of-contents-wordpress-without-plugin/

It's working fine!